# How to implement custom map reduce framework

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to customize map reduce framework implementation. If yes is there any guide like what interfaces to implement and all

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Be more specific about the kind of customizations that you seek.

Comment: Apache ignite has map reduce framework so was wondering is there standard mechanism

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific.

Map Reduce framework allow you to provide your own classes in almost all steps in the map reduce process. Like the input and output classes, how to split the work, etc. By default hadoop include several implementation that are enough in almost all the cases but if not you can provide your own implementation.

If you want to have more control of your process and avoid the limitations imposed by MapReduce specification then you can use Yarn, but in that case you will need to implement all the coordination/communication between your tasks. MapReduceV2 run on top Yarn.

If you want something in the middle you can use frameworks like http://twill.incubator.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

So generally, you will require a mapper and reducer class for your "customized" implementation for map-reduced jobs. The best place to start understanding this is at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html .

The above link is implements a wordcount example which basically counts the number of words across files using the map-reduce framework using hadoop.

The basic "syntax" for a map-reduce job is :

```
public static class IntSumReducer
   extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException 

public static class IntSumReducer
   extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,enter code hereText,IntWritable> {
private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
  //Write reducer code here
}
}
```

As you can see above, the map logic goes in the map method and the reducer logic goes into the reduce method. All your customizations  go here. Ofcourse you can also use combiner methods that will compute the reduce phase but at a local level.

Answer (score 0):

hello world in hadoop (simple map reduce code for understanding how works map reduce paradigm) [more detailed](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v2.0)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils;

public class WordCount2 {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    static enum CountersEnum { INPUT_WORDS }

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    private boolean caseSensitive;
    private Set<String> patternsToSkip = new HashSet<String>();

    private Configuration conf;
    private BufferedReader fis;

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
      conf = context.getConfiguration();
      caseSensitive = conf.getBoolean("wordcount.case.sensitive", true);
      if (conf.getBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", true)) {
        URI[] patternsURIs = Job.getInstance(conf).getCacheFiles();
        for (URI patternsURI : patternsURIs) {
          Path patternsPath = new Path(patternsURI.getPath());
          String patternsFileName = patternsPath.getName().toString();
          parseSkipFile(patternsFileName);
        }
      }
    }

    private void parseSkipFile(String fileName) {
      try {
        fis = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String pattern = null;
        while ((pattern = fis.readLine()) != null) {
          patternsToSkip.add(pattern);
        }
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Caught exception while parsing the cached file '"
            + StringUtils.stringifyException(ioe));
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String line = (caseSensitive) ?
          value.toString() : value.toString().toLowerCase();
      for (String pattern : patternsToSkip) {
        line = line.replaceAll(pattern, "");
      }
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
        Counter counter = context.getCounter(CountersEnum.class.getName(),
            CountersEnum.INPUT_WORDS.toString());
        counter.increment(1);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    GenericOptionsParser optionParser = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args);
    String[] remainingArgs = optionParser.getRemainingArgs();
    if (!(remainingArgs.length != 2 | | remainingArgs.length != 4)) {
      System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out> [-skip skipPatternFile]");
      System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount2.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    List<String> otherArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i < remainingArgs.length; ++i) {
      if ("-skip".equals(remainingArgs[i])) {
        job.addCacheFile(new Path(remainingArgs[++i]).toUri());
        job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", true);
      } else {
        otherArgs.add(remainingArgs[i]);
      }
    }
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs.get(0)));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs.get(1)));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```